# formatting correctly a text to alertdialog

Tags: android

I've a code that transform the seconds to hour(s), minute(s), second(s):

```
int day = (int)TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays((long) val3);        
long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours((long) val3) - (day *24);
long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes((long) val3) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours((long) val3)* 60);
long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds((long) val3) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes((long) val3) *60);
```

also I've the code that write the result:

```
alertDialog.setMessage("Day\t\t" + day + "\nHour\t\t" + hours + "\nMinute\t" + minute + "\nSeconds\t" + second);
```

I need put the correct formatting using \t to separate day, hours, minutes from variables. The problem is that I don't know how many days/hours/minutes I've. So, what's the best way to use \t programmatically?

[image]

Comment: Whats the problem exactly with this code, what is the expected result?

Comment: Juan can you see, the results are not aligned

Comment: oh..so you want it aligned..diagonally..right???

Comment: check if your day, hour, minutes and seconds has more than 1 digit and do it accordingly..isnt that possible??

Comment: Whats the expected output, you want all the numbers aligned vertically, diagonally, or how? Mock it on photoshop or something

Comment: I'd like have all numbers aligned vertically :-)

Comment: One way that will surely work in any case is that you define a custom layout with relative layout having separated textviews for title and number and align them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

To achieve an effect similar to this, create a custom `Dialog` and use a custom layout for it. Modify the values of the inner `TextView` or whatever you want to use to display your data. In my demostration, you could do something as simple as this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
       dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.days)).setText(days);
((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.hours)).setText(hours);
((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.minutes)).setText(minutes);
((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.seconds)).setText(seconds);
//To show, just call dialog.show();
```

The layout that corresponds to `R.layout.dialog` is the following, but keep in mind that you can modify this to fit your exact needs, changing colors sizes, layout and whatever you want. I tried to keep it as concise as possible but we all know that xml layouts are huge, even for the simple ones.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Days"
            android:id="@+id/daysLabel"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hours"
            android:id="@+id/hoursLabel" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Minutes"
            android:id="@+id/minutesLabel"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Seconds"
            android:id="@+id/secondsLabel"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/days" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="42"
            android:id="@+id/hours"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="12"
            android:id="@+id/minutes"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="59"
            android:id="@+id/seconds"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

To summarize, you create an xml layout file that will be shown as the dialog, instead of the default one. This gives you the liberty of deciding what is shown where, without the limitations.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with the number in front of the units, it, you could easily line everything up without needing a custom dialog layout. Just change your [setMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMessage(java.lang.CharSequence)) to:

```
alertDialog.setMessage(String.format("%3d Day\n%3d Hour\n%3d Minute\n%3d Seconds",
                       day, hours, minute, second));
```